# SOAPUI - Groovy scripting - jsonBuilder strips quotes

Tags: groovy, soapui, jsonbuilder

I have a problem where jsonBuilder strips quotes from the result string.  How do I format the output to return a JSON response with quotes ?

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import net.sf.*
import net.sf.json.*
import net.sf.json.groovy.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.*
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import net.sf.json.JSONObject

def ResponseMessage = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["MerchantEMS_POST"].testRequest.response.contentAsString
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
log.info ResponseMessage

def merchantResult = ResponseMessage
def newMerchantID = "60300004055" 
def entityID = jsonSlurper.entityId
jsonSlurper.merchantId   = newMerchantID
def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
def updatedjson = jsonBuilder(jsonSlurper)
log.info "updated JSON = $updatedjson"
```

## return updatedjson

**ResponseMessage** : { "entityId" : "93LSHLXW7BJ5K00MJALWZJMLL0", "creatorId" : "HPCDKMSV763K2VGHCKQQ09QSGM", "createdTimestamp" : "2015-09-02T00:26:34.015Z",   "updaterId" : "HPCDKMSV763K2VGHCKQQ09QSGM", "updatedTimestamp" : "2015-09-02T00:26:34.015Z", "merchantId" : "L7QWKA0001F5W1RRZY4Z006153",
  "createdBy" : "ralgg00",    "isDeleted" : false  }

**updatedjson (no quotes)** = [updatedTimestamp:2015-09-02T00:26:34.015Z, createdBy:ralgg00, createdTimestamp:2015-09-02T00:26:34.015Z, creatorId:HPCDKMSV763K2VGHCKQQ09QSGM, entityId:93LSHLXW7BJ5K00MJALWZJMLL0, merchantId:60300004055, isDeleted:false, updaterId:HPCDKMSV763K2VGHCKQQ09QSGM]

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

When you log the 'updatedjson' it recognises it as Map object and prints its fields. You need to use something that can convert a Map object to JSON and print it out. There are many ways to do this, for example:

```
 def json = JsonOutput.toJson(updatedjson)
 println json
```

Source: http://www.groovy-lang.org/json.html

Comment: Thanks Aston.  I still have the same problem after trying the following additional code with SOAPUI 5.1.2:       def updateJsonString = updatedjson.toString()
log.info "updateJsonString = $updateJsonString"
def strgFormat = new StringWriter()
strgFormat << updateJsonString
log.info "strgFormat = $strgFormat"

Comment: Ok, now I got a solution for you, see the updated answer.

Comment: Hi Aston.  That works (JSON-formatted string out)  once I ADD "import groovy.json.JsonOutput" with def json = JsonOutput.toJson(updatedjson)  !!!  Thanks again.